# WebView in Cocoa not accepting keystrokes?

Tags: cocoa, macos, webview

I'm working on embedding a WebView in Cocoa. I have the basic view up and running, but the problem I'm facing is when I type using either the keyboard or the on-screen keyboard, I get a beep from my Mac and none of the characters are actually shown in the Web view's text field.

I've been going through the web view's reference guide from Apple, but couldn't find anything related to this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Teja.

Comment: Just to be clear, the web views text field has the cursor in it, right? If the cursor is blinking in the text field then that would imply that it has the key focus.

Comment: Actually, I checked again, the text field does not even have a blinking cursor.

Comment: I would guess that it has something to do with the window the WebView is in. Probably it doesn't become the key window. What does [[webView window] canBecomeKeyWindow] return?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was using a borderless window, and apparently you have to over ride `canBecomeKeyWindow` and return YES when creating one.

Answer (score 0):

Omz's comment solved the issue for me. I changed my NSWindow `styleMask` to a style that can become a key window:

```
window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask
```